# How to set String's font size, style in Java using the Font class?

Tags: java, fonts

Suppose I have a String, "Hello World". I want to change the style of this string to a BOLD font, and set the size of all the characters from 12 to 18 [pt]. After that I want to use this string in a `JLabel` and `JButton`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28float%29

JComponent has a setFont() method. You will control the font there, not on the String.

Such as

```
JButton b = new JButton();
b.setFont(b.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
```

Comment: As font is immutable in Java, this solution fits perfectly into the question because the author of this question wants to only change an aspect of the current font of a component.

Answer (score 24):

`Font myFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12);`, then use a setFont method on your components like

```
JButton b = new JButton("Hello World");
b.setFont(myFont);
```