# Updating my Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, java-2d

I'm just starting to learn about programming in Java and even more recently with graphics, and I've run into some problems. 
I want to create a game like dwarf fortress in look, with colored text instead of images.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        g.drawString("[Game goes here]", 100, 150);
        g.dispose();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    g.dispose();
}

public GTest() {
    setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 3, Toolkit
            .getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 3 + 50);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GTest myWindow = new GTest();
}
```

I want it to update the graphics on a timer, but I'm not really sure how to do this.

I know that this is a pretty broad question and I would be happy to clarify anything you might want to know.

EDIT:

So I added this bit:

```
String[] letters = new String[10];
float fontsize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 30;

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(textColor);
    setFont(getFont().deriveFont(fontsize));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if((int) (Math.random() * 100) > 97){
            letters[i] = "w";
            textColor = new Color(0, 0, 100);

        }else{
            letters[i] = "l";
            textColor = new Color(0, 100, 0);
        }
        g.drawString(letters[i], i * 3, 10);
    }
```

But now it doesn't display at all. I added a sysout after the g.drawString and it performed it so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Don't override paint() of a JFrame. That is NOT how you do custom painting. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the proper approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing anything based on a timer in Swing, the [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class is your best friend.

It's JavaDocs explains its usage pretty well, so here's an example.

```
public class GTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private Color textColor = Color.BLACK;
    private Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(textColor);
        g.drawString("[Game goes here]", 100, 150);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textColor = new Color(random.nextInt(0x00ffffff));
        repaint();
    }

    public GTest() {
        setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 3,
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 3 + 50);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Timer timer = new Timer(500, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GTest myWindow = new GTest();
    }
}
```

It's your `GTest` class once again, but this time the text color changes automatically every 0.5 seconds.

Notice two main changes:

1. The constructor now sets up a new instance of `Timer` with no initial delay, period of 500 ms and its listener set up to `this`. That means that this constructed instance will listen to that timer's ticks.
2. To do that, we needed to implement the `ActionListener` interface. This forces us to write the `actionPerformed()` method which gets called every time the Timer ticks. In this method, we change the textcolor to a random one and call `repaint()` which subsequently calls our `paint()` method and gets the text written.

---

P.S. You don't have to `dispose()` your `Graphics` object every time. It's actually said in its JavaDoc, too (emphasize mine):

> Graphics objects which are provided as arguments to the `paint()` and
>   `update()` methods of components are automatically released by the system
>   when those methods return. For efficiency, programmers should call
>   `dispose()` when finished using a `Graphics` object *only if it was created
>   directly from a component or another `Graphics` object*.

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: This is really helpful. Also wondering, how would you change the text size? I tried the two parameters for drawText but that didn't work.

Comment: @Sam From [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630738/how-to-set-strings-font-size-style-in-java-using-font-class), for example, `setFont(getFont().deriveFont(18f));` should work in JFrame. Try googling `java swing font size` to get more answers.

Comment: @sam To change the text size, you need to change the font.

Comment: If you were to use the setFont(getFont...  how would you change the size based on a variable or screenSize or couldn't you.

Comment: @Sam The `18f` part in my last comment is a floating point number (equal to 18.0). That is the size i set. It can, however, be a variable, or any other fraction as long as it's a `float`.

Comment: Don't override paint() of a JFrame. That is NOT how you do custom painting. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the proper approach.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you don't create a copy of the `Graphics` context, you shouldn't be disposing of it.  This could actually prevent other parts of your application form been painted ;)

Second of all. I would avoid extending from a top level container, like `JFrame`, apart from allowing you to draw under the frame/border decoration of the window, they aren't double buffered.

Instead, I'd use something like a `JPanel` instead and override its `paintComponent` method. This will provide you with automatic double buffering.

Because Swing is a single threaded framework, it is expected that all updates to the UI be executed within the context of the Event Diapatching Thread.

This makes live a little difficult when it comes to try to do things like waiting and synchronizing paint updates.

Luckly, Swing provides a `javax.swing.Timer` which allows you schedule an event for some time in the future.  This can also be setup to repeat and regular intervals.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // perform your required actions here
    }
});
```

Now, beware, the `actionPerformed` method is being executed with the context of the EDT, this means, that any long running/time consuming processing you do here may cause you UI to stop painting

Take a look at

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Intial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

For more details...

Comment: @Sam This. Knowledge about the EDT is crucial in Swing programming. Also, about drawing directly into the `JFrame` - every JFrame has a "content pane" which by default is a JPanel. Either swap in your own JPanel or draw directly on the supplied one. Look at [`JFrame#setContentPane()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane%28java.awt.Container%29) and [`getContentPane()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane%28%29).